# How can I make a nested OData call in .NET using OData v4 6.0.0?

Tags: c#, odata, odata-v4

Assuming I have the following in my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<Content>("Content");
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<Area>("Area");
```

And I have the following classes:

```
public class Area
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Area")]
    public int? AreaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make an ODataController action method that is bound to the following route?

```
GET /odata/Area(Id)/Content(Id)
```

When I try to make a custom routing convention, I keep getting the following ODataPath:

```
"~/entityset/key/unresolved"
```

and I'm trying to get this:

```
"~/entityset/key/navigation/key"
```

Note:  I am using v6.0.0 of the v4 OData, so some of the routing has changed from previous versions.

Comment: On your `Area` object, is there a navigation property called `Content`?

Comment: @TomDoesCode - your question led me to the ultimate answer - I had the incorrect name for the Navigation property.  If you submit that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Posted, let me know if that's not accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `Content` in the URL `/odata/Area(Id)/Content(Id)` needs to match the name of the navigation property on the class `Area`. On your class in the question, it is called `Contents`